# How can I make my component to detect the mouse position?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I want to write a little component which shows me on which control mouse is currently over.
When it spot the choosen control it should fire the messaage (for example).

But I don't know what should I do to form to get the position of the mouse all the time.
This is what I've got:

```
  TMouseOverControl = class(TComponent)
  private
    fActive: Boolean;
    fControl: TWinControl;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure Loaded; override;
    procedure SpotIt;
  published
    property Active: Boolean read fActive write fActive;
    property Control: TWinControl read fControl write fControl; // when mouse is over this control show me the message
  end;

constructor TMouseOverControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  // nothing interesting here
  // don't have control property here - so overrided the loaded method
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMouseOverControl.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;

  //  TForm(Owner).Mo.... := SpotIt.... 
  //  what should i do to make it work?
 end;

 procedure TMouseOverControl.SpotIt;
 begin
// IsMouseOverControl is easy to implement
// http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2010/qt/is-some-delphi-tcontrol-under-the-mouse.htm
       if IsMouseOverControl(Control) then 
         ShowMessage('Yep, U got it!');
     end;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't the Application.OnIdle event work as demonstrated by your [own link](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2010/qt/is-some-delphi-tcontrol-under-the-mouse.htm)?

Comment: @NGLN So I should override it with my own event?

Comment: Ah sorry, of course you want it to be part of your component. Duh...

Comment: You could use a timer, a MouseHook or a subclass of the control (since it is a TWinControl).

Comment: @NGLN The Control is just to make it easier to read. I have a TCollection of controls. MouseHook seems a little bit complicated, but a timer can do it's job

Comment: Do you want the position of the mouse all the time from when it enters the control to when it exits, or you want the mouse position all the time, polling it even when the control itself is not active, or the form that it is on is not focused, active or visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you only need to check/update when the mouse moves. So you could track `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages by using `TApplicationEvents`.

```
// Edit: these variables are intended to be private fields of the component class
var
  FAppEvents: TApplicationEvents;
  FFoundControl: Boolean;
  FCurrentControl: TWinControl;

procedure TMyComponent.HandleAppMessage(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  Control: TWinControl;
begin
  if (Msg.message = WM_MOUSEMOVE) and not FFoundControl then
  begin
    Control:= FindControl(Msg.hwnd);
    if Assigned(Control) then
    begin
      FCurrentControl:= Control;
      FFoundControl:= True;
    end;
  end else
  if (Msg.message = WM_MOUSELEAVE) then
    FFoundControl:= False;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FAppEvents:= TApplicationEvents.Create(nil);
  FAppEvents.OnMessage:= HandleAppMessage;
end;
```

This could certainly be optimized, e.g. by also checking for WM_MOUSELEAVE so you don't have to `FindControl` on every mouse move. This solution works for `TWinControls` and descendants.

**Edit**: Made use of WM_MOUSELEAVE.

Comment: +1 TApplicationEvents is not _singleton like_. I completely forgot about that.

Comment: Though I think the `PtInRect` solution from [OP's link](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2010/qt/is-some-delphi-tcontrol-under-the-mouse.htm) is a better solution in AppEvents.OnIdle. Also, your variables should be private fields.

Comment: @NGLN I was just too lazy to write the component class. The variables are not intended to be global variables. I added a comment.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
// rectangle where you are interested to check if the mouse is into..
targetRect := Rect(0, 0, ImageZoom.Width, ImageZoom.Height);

// find out where the mouse is..
mousePosition := Point(0, 0);
GetCursorPos(mousePosition);

// find out if the point.. from screen to client.. is inside that rectangle
isMouseInside := (PtInRect(targetRect, ScreenToClient(mousePosition)));
```